# Flutter: Provider and Firebase | List of Object from Firestore Data (mapped) returns null from Provider

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I'm pretty new in Flutter. So, currently I'm using a Provider package in my project, where it simply take a snaphot (`QuerySnapshot`) from the Firestore collection then mapped it into `TaskObject` (a custom object that I created) then convert the mapped Task Object into a List. The problem is: when I use `Provider.of<List<TaskObject>>(context)` in the UI dart file, it returns null. This UI dart file got a parent file that has `StreamProvider` with `catchError` properties and it does catch an error. Here's my code:

[1. The UI dart file source code](https://carbon.now.sh/?bg=rgba%28143%2C176%2C196%2C1%29&t=night-owl&wt=none&l=dart&ds=true&dsyoff=20px&dsblur=68px&wc=true&wa=true&pv=56px&ph=56px&ln=false&fl=1&fm=Hack&fs=14px&lh=133%25&si=false&es=2x&wm=false&code=List%253CTaskObject%253E%2520toDoList%2520%253D%2520Provider.of%253CList%253CTaskObject%253E%253E%28context%29%2520%253F%253F%2520%255B%255D%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F...%250A%250AColumn%28%250A%2509mainAxisAlignment%253A%2520MainAxisAlignment.start%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520children%253A%2520%255B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2509Container%28%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2509height%253A%2520MediaQuery.of%28context%29.size.height%2520*%25200.3%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2509child%253A%2520ListView.builder%28%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2509physics%253A%2520BouncingScrollPhysics%28%29%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520scrollDirection%253A%2520Axis.vertical%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520itemCount%253A%2520toDoList.length%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520itemBuilder%253A%2520%28context%252C%2520index%29%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520print%28toDoList%255Bindex%255D%29%253B%2520%252F%252Freturns%2520null%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520CustomCheckboxListTile%28%252F%252Fjust%2520a%2520normal%2520checkbox%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2509activeColor%253A%2520Theme.of%28context%29.primaryColor%252C%2520%252F%252Fchange%2520to%2520tag%2520color%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520value%253A%2520toDoList%255Bindex%255D.completed%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520onChanged%253A%2520%28value%29%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2509setState%28%28%29%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520toDoList%255Bindex%255D.completed%2520%253D%253D%2520false%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%253F%2520toDoList%255Bindex%255D.completed%2520%253D%2520true%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%253A%2520toDoList%255Bindex%255D.completed%2520%253D%2520false%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%29%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520title%253A%2520Text%28%2522%2524%257BtoDoList%255Bindex%255D.task%257D%2522%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520style%253A%2520GoogleFonts.karla%28%29.copyWith%28%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2509color%253A%2520Theme.of%28context%29.accentColor%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520fontSize%253A%252018%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520fontWeight%253A%2520FontWeight.w500%29%29%29%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%29%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%29%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%255D%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%29%253B)

[2. The Database Service source code (Mapping Processes)](https://carbon.now.sh/?bg=rgba%28143%2C176%2C196%2C1%29&t=night-owl&wt=none&l=dart&ds=true&dsyoff=20px&dsblur=68px&wc=true&wa=true&pv=56px&ph=56px&ln=false&fl=1&fm=Hack&fs=14px&lh=133%25&si=false&es=2x&wm=false&code=%2520%2520List%253CTaskObject%253E%2520_taskObjectFromSnapshot%28QuerySnapshot%2520data%29%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520data.docs.map%28%28element%29%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520print%28element%255B%2522date%2522%255D%2520is%2520String%29%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520TaskObject%28%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520task%253A%2520element%255B%2522taskName%2522%255D%2520%253F%253F%2520%2522%2522%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520date%253A%2520element%255B%2522date%2522%255D%2520%253F%253F%2520%2522%2522%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520tags%253A%2520element%255B%2522tags%2522%255D%2520%253F%253F%2520%255B%255D%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520description%253A%2520element%255B%2522taskDescription%2522%255D%2520%253F%253F%2520%2522%2522%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520completed%253A%2520element%255B%2522isCompleted%2522%255D%2520%253F%253F%2520false%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%29%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%29.toList%28%29%253B%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%250A%2520%2520Stream%253CList%253CTaskObject%253E%253E%2520get%2520taskObject%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520isGuest%2520%253D%253D%2520false%2520%253F%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520users.doc%28currentUser.uid%29.collection%28%2522to-do-collection%2522%29.snapshots%28%29.map%28_taskObjectFromSnapshot%29%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%253A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520UserData%28name%253A%2520currentUser.displayName%2520%253F%253F%2520%2522%2522%29%253B%250A%2520%2520%257D)

[image: My Firestore database structure.]

Note : In the database service code, I've printed some of the Firestore data, and it's perfectly working. But I don't know how to check whether the object is filled with those Firestore data or not before streamed the List into Provider.

Thank you so much guys! All helps provided will be highly appreciated. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the firestore data hasn't finished reading but your ListView.builder widget already showned. So your todolist hasn't been filled yet. Try this code

Note: Use `notifyListeners();` to notify changes on your state value

```
toDoList.length == null
    ? Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      )
    : Container(
        child: ListView.builder(),
      ),
```

Comment: Where should I use notifyListeners()?